# Hide MS ACCESS DB FILE

Tags: ms-access

I am currently using an access DB with front and back end. When I want to allow new users to access the DB I add the user to the folder in which the DB is housed. Essentially if they determined the path of the DB they could copy it ect.

Is there anyway to still allow access to the DB through the Access front end yet still prevent the user from actually getting to the directory of the file.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: It's at this sort of point where you're effectively wanting client/server separation that you'd usually be considering replacing the access back-end with e.g. a SQL Server one.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't access is a file based dbms. For the app the user is running as to see the file, the user has to be able to.

This is the sort of need that says access cannot be used. Well not directly , you could use access as a backend, ie you park it behind some sort of service and your front end hits that.

Answer (score -2):

yo keep an integral copy for you in case of changes then with the pblic copy, for example

with Access 2007  you click files -> Options -> active data base -> Navigation Options.
then you hide all the elements...